# android support v7 util missing

Tags: android, build, android-support-library

I have tryed to install the Support7Demos application on Android Studio.
If i run the Project, i get the following error:

```
Error:(21, 31) error: package android.support.v7.util does not exist
```

My Gradle file includes the following libraries:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.2"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

I'm using the following build tools:

```
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: You have to download them through the SDK manager: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: They are already installed

Answer (score 4):

Finally, i figured it out:

The Solution is: Adding the right Version:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.0'
//        compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```